# how to switch direction (ltr to rtl) dinamiclly while changing language?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internationalization, right-to-left

I bought a dashboard ui template for my react project,
i read the documentation and implemented the RTL version but it's a one way,
my goal is to set the direction of the HTML side by side with the language,
i want each language will transfer the direction by the language default direction,
arabic - rtl
hebrew - rtl
english - ltr etc...

https://gist.github.com/carmelodevuz/9ee0d92db7bd15c3612e25356139c4f9

thanks.

I tried implementing the "how-to.md" from the docs (linked it here..)